# Matrix-output for FFNN?

Tags: feedforward-neural-networks

Turns out that it looks like I will be approximating a 100x10 matrix in my project thesis. II have the following equation

$y = Dx$,

where $y$ is $(100 \times 1)$, $D$ is $100 \times 10$ and $x$ is $10 \times 1$

It is the transformation matrix $D$ I will be approximating by iterating over quite alot of pairs (x,y). I was wondering if it is possible to output a $(100 \times 10)$ matrix as output in a FFNN-architecture, or is there any other ways to do it? As this is not an image or anything similar which gives rise to pooling etc., my guess is that CNN is not ideal here.

So tldr: Is it easy to use feed-forward architecture to approximate an matrix?

EDIT: I figured out that $D$ obviously doesn't need to be a mtrxi, just have 100 output nodes, duh. Thanks.

Comment: short answer: yes it is possibly to predict a matrix as an output of a FFNN. instead of one output neuron you need to have an N output neurons because in this case you want to output a matrix of shape (m,n)